# Does dd care when cloning from smaller hdd to bigger hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, ubuntu-12.04, clone, dd

Does DD care about hard drive size?

I currently have a smaller 500GB HDD that i want cloned to a 1TB SSD. Will it clone without a problem relating to size? will there be non partitioned space?

was going to run it simply as:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb/ bs=4096
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dd` will literally write byte for byte onto the `of` disk. You will end up with 500gb of unpartitioned space. That being said, you can use a tool like gparted to resize the partition after you are done with `dd`

Comment: Awesome. can i use fdisk to expand the partition? this is a non GUI environment?

Comment: yes, fdisk is one cmd-tool that let's you resize a partition.